# Highstocks dynamic graph - timeslider graph pattern issue

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highstocks dynamic graph with time slider something similar to  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});

// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '1M'
        }, {
            count: 5,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '5M'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 0
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

The only difference I have is that I can have 1 to n number of lines in the graph which will keep on updating after a particular time period. Now my question is

1. Although I have multiple line graphs plotted on the top but I see only one line graph in the bottom of the graph inside my time slider. Is it expected or the time slider should also have the same number of graphs as on top of the graph?
2. What does the line graph inside the time slider on the bottom of the graph signifies? I can't see the pattern of the bottom graph similar to any of my top graph pattern. Does high chart takes the union of all the top graphs and then constructs one single bottom graph pattern or is there any other logic for the pattern of the bottom time slider graph.Pls, explain.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create the issue

For issue 1 and 2 mentioned above will be addressed by [navigator](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/navigator)

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            showInNavigator: true
        }
    },
```

Each of the line graph will be visible in navigator  using `showInNavigator: true`

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  global: {
    useUTC: false
  }
});

// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {

        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
        var series1 = this.series[1];
        setInterval(function() {
          var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            y1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 10),
            y2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
          series.addPoint([x, y1], true, true);
          series1.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  },

  rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
      count: 1,
      type: 'minute',
      text: '1M'
    }, {
      count: 5,
      type: 'minute',
      text: '5M'
    }, {
      type: 'all',
      text: 'All'
    }],
    inputEnabled: false,
    selected: 0
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Live random data'
  },

  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      showInNavigator: true
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    data: (function() {
      // generate an array of random data
      var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        i;

      for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
        data.push([
          time + i * 1000,
          Math.round(Math.random() * 10)
        ]);
      }
      return data;
    }())
  }, {
    name: 'Random data1',
    data: (function() {
      // generate an array of random data
      var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        i;

      for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
        data.push([
          time + i * 1000,
          Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
        ]);
      }
      return data;
    }())
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

For *I can't see the pattern of the bottom graph similar to any of my top graph pattern*, yes it is almost same, due to mini size of the actual graph in navigator

Comment: showInNavigator did solve my problem. Thanks! Is there any API where I can make the time slider selected range get updated whenever the graph is updating ?right now I see the time slider always remains selected where it was for the first time ? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you want time slider variable on what situation. Can you add example fiddle example which shows the issue

Comment: check the official example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/members/axis-setextremes/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set `showInNavigator` property inside each series.
2. In Highstock, dataGrouping is enabled in navigator series, unless you disable it with `navigator.series.dataGrouping.enabled`. Also, navigator shows the whole range, so compare it with main series when it shows full range too.

Examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/pgr1st89/ - using showInNavigator
http://jsfiddle.net/vomu0xug/ - disabling dataGrouping and showing the whole range